# Is it good to use "for you" or "for me" in business communications

Tags: syntactic-analysis

While talking to business, how bad it is to use language like "We will do this for you" or "can you do this for me". Are both of these sentences are not acceptable/not good to use

Comment: Why would it be bad?

Comment: Got this feedback in Business Communication training. Does this give a sense of less professionalism?

Comment: No. Absolutely not. I'm not even sure what exactly it is you were told not to use. First/second person pronouns in general? Just the phrase “for me/us/you”? The specific phrase “What can I/we/you do for you/me/us”? The latter does sound a bit curt and demanding for most business communication, but not because of the pronouns.

Comment: Yeah; thank...it is "for you" or "for me" phrases

Comment: If the context and sentence calls for it, there is nothing inappropriate about using those phrases in business communication.

Comment: You might also try asking this question in workplace.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 2):

"can you do this for me?" is not wrong but you can be more polite and use this "Would you please do this for me?" OR "Would you mind doing this for me?".

And about "We will do this for you", it is not at all wrong. OR you can say this "We do not mind doing this for you.".